# How to get previous 12 months data in SQL Server and avoiding the current month

Tags: sql-server

I have a column called `Sale Date` in my table and I want to get the 12 months data without the current month. I.e., since we are in April 2021, the query needs to show data from April 2020 to March 2021. What should be the condition in the where clause be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, evaluates to `>='2020-04-01 00:00:00.000'` and `<'2021-04-01 00:00:00.000'` (which encompasses to end of March 23:59:59)

```
where Datecolumn >=DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month, 0, DateAdd(month,-12,GetDate())), 0)
and dateColumn < DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month, 0, GetDate()), 0)
```

Comment: Will this work even if i am in the middle of April month say i am on April 15th , but i still need From last year April 1 2020 till March 31 2021

Comment: I will add days to getdate and check and getback

Comment: So what you are doing here is selecting dates from previous 12 months in the first part of the where clause and in the second clause for the current month getting the first day and limiting records to prior that day. so it filters out current month. Thanks for the help. This works

Comment: Cool .Glad it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
where DATEDIFF(MM,SaleDate,GETDATE())<=12
and SaleDate < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Comment: what does this do  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0). I know that datediff will return 4 months , but what happens after that

Comment: `DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())` will give you the number of months from `1900-01-01` until now.  So then in `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` that same number of months is added back to `1900-01-01` to get the start of the current month.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WHERE SaleDate >= DATEADD(year, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1))
  AND SaleDate < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)
```

Say we were on `15 April 2021`:

In that case, `DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)` returns `1 April 2021` and `DATEADD(year, -1, ...` returns `1 April 2020`.

Because we have a half-open interval `>= AND <`, we can get the period from exactly `1 April 2020 00:00:00` up to **but not including** `1 April 2021 00:00:00`.

Comment: Will this work even if i am in the middle of April month say i am on April 15th , but i still need From last year April 1 2020 till March 31 2021

Comment: Thank you very much, i got it, i am new to stackoverflow, how can i accept two answers as correct , above solution by Stu also is correct

Comment: You can't, but you can upvote both, you can also change which one you want to accept

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?  (4/1/2020 and 3/31/2021)

```
Select * FROM TBL1
WHERE SalesDate > DATEADD(YEAR, -1,  CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, 
GETDATE()), 0)))
and SalesDate < CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MS, -3, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) , 
0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Today's date = getdate().
Date of first day of this month (first day of April) = convert(datetime, concat(year(getdate()), '-', month(getdate()), '-01'), 120). This is your end date. Start date is 12 months before end date = dateadd(month, -12, ...).
So here's your where clause...

```
where [sale date] >= dateadd(month, -13, convert(datetime, concat(year(getdate()), '-', month(getdate()), '-01'), 120))
and [sale date] < convert(datetime, concat(year(getdate()), '-', month(getdate()), '-01'), 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way to do this than all the posted answers:

```
WHERE
  saledate >= dateadd(d,1,eomonth(getutcdate(),-13)) AND
  saledate < dateadd(d,1,eomonth(getutcdate(),-1))
```

If saledate is just the date, no time, it gets simpler:

```
WHERE
  saledate > eomonth(getutcdate(),-13) AND
  saledate <= eomonth(getutcdate(),-1)
```

Note; if your dates are not stored in UTC (they perhaps should be) then use GetDate() rather than GetUTCDate()