# How do I get last 12 months of data based on available data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table test with columns sales and date. The requirement is to get the last available 12 months of data without the current month. For example say that there is data available till 2010 march 5th. The query needs to fetch data from 2009 march till 2010 feb. what would be the where clause on date be in SQL Server

Comment: This is absolutely no different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66907359/how-to-get-previous-12-months-data-in-ms-sql-server-and-avoiding-the-current-mon). Same logic, just a different starting point.

Comment: but i cannot use the getdate()  function in this scenario , i need to fetch the last date from the db and use it, is there a function to do so

Comment: Use the MAX() aggregate to get the latest value of whatever date column is in your table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get previous 12 months data in SQL Server and avoiding the current month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66907359/how-to-get-previous-12-months-data-in-sql-server-and-avoiding-the-current-month)

Comment: SO is not a replacement for tutorials. Take time to go through one or two on SQL as the basics should cover this topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Sales, Date FROM Test
WHERE Date BETWEEN 
    DATEADD(m,-12,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, '05/Mar/2010'), 0)) 
    AND 
    DATEADD(m, 0,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, '05/Mar/2010'), 0)) - 1
```